# How to tag Twitter friends in Instagram?

Tags: twitter, instagram

I've recently begun using Instagram as my primary photo app, but I've been having trouble tagging Twitter friends when I hit "Share Photo" > "Twitter" from within the app.

By default, Instagram autofills the Tweet field with whatever I've written for the photo caption. Very often, these captions include an "@ tag" or two -- basically just Twitter handles that I remember from memory. Sometimes they are activated as Instagram user names, but very often they are not. No matter what, the name is fully written and prepended with an "@" within Instagram -- What I see is what I get within the app.

But then when I share on Twitter, very often the "@" disappears. My friends aren't tagged when I tweet.

I understand this has something to do with Instagram's auto-detection of Instagram user names. But how can I ensure that What I see is What I get when I share an Instagram via Twitter?

Comment: Just want to add that this could also be called: "How does Instagram convert account names when sharing to Twitter". That's the question I came for and the top answer answers it with a source.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really, unless all your Instagram contacts also use the same handle on Twitter.

But if the people you're tagging on Instagram also have a linked Twitter account, even if it's a different name, the tweet will convert the usernames as necessary.

> If the @mentioned user has connected Instagram to Twitter:
>
> - The user’s Instagram username will appear in the photo caption
> - The user’s Twitter username will appear in the tweet
>
> If the @mentioned user has not connected Instagram to Twitter:
>
> - The user’s Instagram username will appear in the photo caption
> - The @ sign will be removed from the username when shared to Twitter
>
> [Instagram @mentions now translate to Twitter](http://blog.instagram.com/post/33899391168/instagram-mentions-now-translate-to-twitter)

Comment: Wow, why is that only on Tumblr LOL. I searched their docs for Twitter and found nothing but apparently I should have been checking Tumblr.

Answer (score -1):

I've found using two @'s does the trick.

Comment: Where did you find that?